# Wrong width of view on startup of iPad app in iOS 7

Tags: ios, ipad, ios7, orientation

If your device (simulator or iPad) is in landscape orientation and you start the app while querying the width you get wrong results. One should get 1024 but in fact I'm getting 768 which is completely wrong. On iOS 8 this does work as expected. On iPhone and iOS 7 the view is first in portrait but then changes quickly to landscape which works for my case.

In `viewDidLoad` I'm getting the the size with `View.Bounds.Size.Width`. If you rotate the device and query the data in `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` the data is correct. For my app I don't need this in `viewDidLoad`, but in another method. But in `viewDidLoad` it seems to be the same behavior.

What's wrong here? How do I get the correct width of the view on iOS 7 and iOS 8?

Comment: for what purpose do you need the screen width and height? are you using auto layout? most issues with screen size can be avoided if one uses auto layout.

Comment: try this in `viewDidLayoutSubviews:` method. You will get right results.

Comment: @HashmatKhalil: I'm having the problem that `layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath` is returning the [wrong size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31542783/ios-7-keeping-the-displayed-items-in-the-viewing-area-after-rotation-of-uicolle). Now I try to find the cause for this. While searching for this I found that the size isn't correct at the startup. I need the size for sizing the elements in the collection view.

Comment: ok now i know what for you need the size. you should set the size of your collection view cell size in the delegate collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:

Comment: @HashmatKhalil: I'm currently doing this and the cell size is correct, except on iOS7 iPad at the startup (but I'll use `viewDidLayoutSubviews` or similar and save the width in a variable). I think for this question that should be the solution, but if you have some tips for my `layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath` problem I'd be glad.

Comment: @HashmatKhalil: Interesting. The `layoutSubviews` method of the collection view is first called with the wrong size. Afterwards, the `collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:` is called, which calculates the wrong cell width. Then `layoutSubviews` is called again multiple times with the correct size. But `collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:` is never called again (except on rotation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try getting the width in `viewDidLayoutSubviews:` or any other method that comes after that in the view hierarchy such as `viewDidAppear:`

Hope this helps you.