# scrollToItemAtIndexPath before the view is shown the first time

Tags: ios, ios7, scroll, uicollectionview

I have a `UIView` where I added a `UICollectionView`. Now this view is shown on app start up. At the same time I'm scrolling to a certain position in my collection view. Therefore I use `scrollToItemAtIndexPath`. The problem now is that it scrolls to a wrong position, because the collection view has the wrong size at the beginning: If you start the iPad in the landscape orientation on iOS 7 the collection view always takes 768 as width despite it is in landscape.

How can I scroll to a certain position without the user noticing it? Where in the view hierarchy can I call it?

`viewWillAppear`: frames have not been set
`viewDidAppear`: not possible without the user noticing it
`layoutSubviews`: this is called multiple times and I only need it at startup and when the user presses a button

I also tried to use `layoutIfNeeded`, but that doesn't help for my edge case (iOS 7, iPad, landscape at startup).

Comment: constraints kick around the time viewDidAppear and layoutSubviews is called for the last time. By that time it's too late. You can try inheriting your own class from `UICollectionView` and see if its `layoutSubviews` has correct constraints and call `scrollToIndex` from there. 

If that fails, you can cheat by setting frame sizes in viewDidLoad and calling scroll to index. ( This one is a tad bit more complicated)

Comment: @iosDev82: I tried your first described way by using a boolean so that it is only called one time. Additionally I check if the width is greater zero. With this apporach the collection view isn't shown at all and I get the following output in the console: *negative or zero sizes are not supported in the flow layout*. Without `scrollToItemAtIndexPath` called in `layoutSubviews` of the collection view everything is shown fine (except the scrolling position). How should I check the correct constraints?

Comment: Now I did this after the call to `[super layoutSubviews];` and it seems to work for the first tests. Additionally, I removed the animation. I'll test it a little bit more though. Is this the intended behavior by Apple or is this a bug in iOS 7?

Comment: I think it's the intended behavior by Apple and it really sucks. I think constraints should get resolved by `viewDidLoad` or at least `viewWillAppear`. Let us know if all your tests pass. :)

Comment: You can post your comment as an answer. I had to restructure some other calls (needed `layoutIfNeeded`), but now it should work. I have a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31542783/ios-7-keeping-the-displayed-items-in-the-viewing-area-after-rotation-of-uicolle). Perhaps you can have a look at it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constraints kick around the time `viewDidAppear` and `layoutSubviews` is called for the last time. By that time it's too late.

You can try inheriting your own class from UICollectionView and see if its `layoutSubviews` has correct constraints and call `scrollToIndex` from there.

If that fails, you can cheat by setting frame sizes in `viewDidLoad` and calling scroll to index. ( This one is a tad bit more complicated) –